# cast.Api.addReceiverListener() callback when device status changes

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

As per the Chromecast API on [cast.Api.addReceiverListener()](https://developers.google.com/cast/reference/chrome/jsdoc/cast.Api#addReceiverListener), the description for this method is as follows:

> Adds a listener function that with the current list of receivers that supports the given activity type. When added, the listener will be called immediately with the current list, and whenever the list of receivers changes.

Why doesn't it call the callback when device status such as `isTabProjected` changes. How else can I get a callback when such status change?

Answer (score 0):

The listener mentioned is called only when the list of receivers change, i.e. if a new one is added or one is dropped off. Currently, the other type of listeners that can be registered by calling addMediaStatusListener is called when the status of media changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking specifically for events that occur as a result of the tab closing/reloading, you can use:

cast.Api.setReloadTabRequestHandler